# Issue with managed function being passed as call back function in unmanaged structure (C++, C#)

Tags: c#, c++

This is the C++ structure:

```
typedef struct strImageAcq
{
    int                   theHandle;
    uint8_t*          theImageBuf;
    uint32_t*             theImageBufSizePtr;
    const struct timeval* theTimeout;
    int                   ImageStatus;
    CallBackFunc          AcqImageCallBack;
    void *                CallBackParameters;
}strImageAcq;

struct timeval {
    long    tv_sec;         /* seconds */
    long    tv_usec;        /* and microseconds */
};

typedef void (CALLBACK *CallBackFunc)(void *);
```

And this is C++ function I need to call:

```
int AcqImage(strImageAcq* myImageAcq);
```

This is the managed code I constructed:

```
[DllImport(CameraDll, EntryPoint = "AcqImage", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int AcquireImage(IntPtr ImgStr);

 delegate void CallBack();

    internal struct timeval
    {
        internal int tv_sec;     //seconds
        internal int tv_usec;    //microseconds
    };

  internal struct ImageAcq
    {
        internal int handle;
        internal IntPtr ImageBuf;
        internal IntPtr ImageBufSizePtr;
        internal IntPtr Timeout;
        internal int ImageStatus;
        internal IntPtr AcqImgCallBack;
        internal IntPtr CallbackParms;
    };

private static void MyCallBackFunc()
{
        Console.WriteLine("Function MyCallBackFunc called.");
}

IntPtr SerialBufList;
IntPtr pAcqImg;
IntPtr pImgBuf;
IntPtr pImgSize;
IntPtr pTimeout;
IntPtr pCallBack;
timeval Timeout = new timeval();  
Timeout.tv_sec = 3;
ImageSize = 386000;


 //filling  the structure to be sent to AcquireImage
        pImgBuf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal( (int)ImageSize * sizeof(byte)); //initial buffer


        pImgSize = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(uint)); //image buffer size pointer
        Marshal.WriteInt32(pImgSize, (int)ImageSize);

        pTimeout = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(Timeout)); //timeout structure 
        Timeout.tv_sec = 2;
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(Timeout, pTimeout, true);

        FunctionPointer = new CallBack(MyCallBackFunc);
        pCallBack = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(FunctionPointer);

        AcqImg.handle = DetectorHandle[0];
        AcqImg.ImageBuf = pImgBuf;
        AcqImg.ImageBufSizePtr = pImgSize;
        AcqImg.ImageStatus = -8;
        AcqImg.Timeout = pTimeout;
        AcqImg.AcqImgCallBack = pCallBack;
        AcqImg.CallbackParms = IntPtr.Zero;

        pAcqImg = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(AcqImg));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(AcqImg, pAcqImg, true);
       // MyCallBackFunc();
        rv = AcquireImage(pAcqImg);
        ErrorCheck(rv, "AcquireImage");

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pImgBuf);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pImgSize);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pTimeout);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pAcqImg);
```

Now as soon as it calls   `rv = AcquireImage(ref pImgAcq);` previously I used to get message vshost32.exe has stopped working. Now the managed call back function is not being called. Besides that everything seems to be working fine. I have edited the text to update the progress. Also what I did is that I wrote an unmanaged wrapper around the unmanaged code that just takes the parameter from the managed code and passes it to library. The reason for doing this is check whether right parameters are being passed from the managed code to unmanaged code and in this case the right address is being passed. The question is why is that my call back function(delegate) is not being executed?

Comment: Is callback invoked from the same thread?

Comment: I don't think you need "ref" in  AcquireImage(IntPtr ImgStr) import declaration.

Comment: @alexm, you were right. ref is not required. However now the only thing not working as expected is call back function. Also, call back is invoked from separate thread.

Comment: I suggest not try to pass C++ struct to C# and back, I suggest writing C bridging function which passes the members as parameters and build C++/C# struct on the other side

Comment: @David Haim: that what I am planning to do actually. Write unmanaged wrapper around the library to manage the callback function and just pass the data to managed C# code, instead passing structures around. But the funny thing is I see the same address of delegate(function pointer) on the managed and unmanaged side, however the unmanaged code is not able to call the managed  function.

Comment: Most obvious mistake is the delegate declaration, it needs an IntPtr parameter to match the CallBackFunc pointer type.  Pretty unlikely that pImgBuf is large enough, cameras don't use a single byte per pixel anymore.  Make it 4 times as large.  Do use a telephone to get in touch with the author of this code, he can trivially tell you where his code bombs.

Answer (score -1):

A data pointer means absolutely nothing when passed between C# and C++, it is just an integer.  In C#, a managed pointer points into the managed heap, which is not accessible by externally referenced native code, and can even be relative to the location of the heap (not a real pointer at all).  In C++, a pointer points into process space memory, which is not part of the managed heap of C#, and therefore cannot be accessed from managed code.

Structs in C# are not guaranteed to conform to any organization rules, such as the in-memory order, or how much padding exists between elements of different sizes.  In C++, you can specify padding for structs during compile, and the members are guaranteed to be in the order you specify at declaration.  So, except by chance, your struct in C# will not be compatible with your struct in C++.

Originally, I wrote that managed code cannot be called from native code.  This is technically wrong in simple cases, because .NET has the ability to marshal the call as an explicit unmanaged function call, such as described here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/318140/How-to-make-a-callback-to-Csharp-from-C-Cplusplus

This doesn't change the overall issue of passing data between managed and unmanaged, although with the support for marshalling, it may be possible to do without COM, but even if it is, I suspect it will be difficult and very fragile, and probably leak native memory due to the LoadLibrary timings.

To make this work as you describe it, you will need to modify your C++ .DLL to implement and support COM, so you can use the shared COM model (.NET is based on COM) to marshal data between native and managed code.  I have done some COM work in the past, which is the primary reason I stick with native code.

What does AcqImage do, and is there any way to do it within .NET?  Does a library/framework/toolkit exist that can do it for you, and handle the COM interop with .NET so you don't have to?  Or, can you write your application in C++ instead and avoid the interop problem?

Comment: `Managed code cannot be called from native code` - this is totaly wrong and I hav done it several times without using COM wrappers.

Comment: @David Haim: how did you do it without using COM wrappers?